# Java to Teradata connectivity

Tags: java, teradata

Iam trying to connect to Teradata using Java JDBC. I have giving the connection string, userid,password.

But iam ending up with the error as

"No Class definition error for Java/Sql/ParameterMetaData "

I have tdgssconfig.jar, rt.jar and terajdbc4.jar in my classpath. Tried google/bing for the solutions, but in vain.

Any inputs/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: java 1.3.1 .This is the version we had in our client enviornment.

Comment: ParameterMetaData was introduced in Java 1.4 You may have to use a higher version of Java to be able to use the library.

Comment: @Rajeev : So, any workaround/alternative solution for Java 1.3.1

Comment: You may have to use the appropriate version of JDBC connector compatible with Java 1.3. See this [link](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-jdbc-driver-13-0-0-6) if it helps.

Comment: 1.3.1 is so old, that it pre-dates official end of life dates (or end of free support). The first version to be EOL'ed was Java 1.4.2 six years ago.